# Not able to assign default value from costume directive to select control

Tags: angularjs

I have simple scenario with costume directive in angularjs. In which if there will be only one item in drop down it would be selected by default else it work as normal drop down list.

for that I try below code,

```js
var app = angular.module("testapp", []);
(function () {
    'use strict';
    angular.module('testapp').controller('TestCtrl', ['$scope', TestCtrl]);
    function TestCtrl($scope) {
        $scope.Test=[];
        $scope.Test.id=0;
        $scope.data = [{
            "id": 1,
            "name": "abc"            
        }];
    }
})()

angular.module('testapp').directive('advanceDropdown', function () {
    var directive = {}
    directive.restrict = 'A';   
    directive.require = 'ngModel';
    directive.scope = {
        items: '=advanceDropdown'

    }
    directive.link = function (scope, element, attrs, ctrl) {
        if (scope.items.length == 1) {
            element.val(scope.items[0]);
        }
    }
    return directive;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.4.2/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="testapp" ng-controller="TestCtrl"> 
      <select name="ddlTest" ng-model="Test.id"  ng-options="d.id as d.name for d in data" advance-dropdown="data"  required>
                <option value="" ng-selected="selected" disabled>--Select--</option>
       </select>
</div>
```

but it can't works. what I missing in the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is correct, only a small issue inside directive, try the following please

```
directive.link = function (scope, element, attrs, ctrl) {
    if (scope.items.length == 1) {
        element.val = scope.items[0];
    }
}
```

**[Demo](https://plnkr.co/edit/gB5UItoFfe7A2y24Vslg?p=preview)**